# How to make muliple fields editable generated from database?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

So i've got a database with about 100 records, these records get shown on a website where you are supposed to edit them.

The generated result looks like this at the moment:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">bukkit.command.help</a></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="2" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">essentials.afk</a></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="3" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">essentials.list</a></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="4" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">essentials.sethome.bed</a></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="5" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">essentials.tpaccept</a></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="6" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">itemcase.buy</a></div>
```

As you may or may not have guessed by now these are minecarft permissions (however irrelevent to this issue).

To edit these i would like to use X-editable but since all have the same id they can't be edited (except for the first record).

I could change the generation so that they each get a unique id just like the data-pk element.
However this would cause trouble in the javascript file since i would have to add a new like of javascript for each element then.

Current my javascript is like this:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$('#permission').editable();
```

But as mentioned before this will only work for the first result. I could staticly define each element to be editable, but thats not possible since the amount of data is unknow beforehand and dynamic.

How can i go about making fields like these editable?

Comment: ID attributes should be unique; there should only be one `#permission` on any page you visit. You probably want to give the individual items `class="permission"` instead

Comment: Does X-editable supports class selector?

Answer (score 0):

I think your structure is

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#" id="permission" ....>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#" id="permission" ....>
</div>
```

Give each element a unique id
change `<div class="row">` to `<div class="row" id="permissions">`
finally change you JavaScript code to

```
$('#permissions a').editable();
```

Changing the JavaScript to this line of code will catch all `<a>` elements within the #permissions element. Take a look at [this](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content in a parent element like below.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">bukkit.command.help</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="2" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">essentials.afk</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="3" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">essentials.list</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="4" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">essentials.sethome.bed</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="5" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">essentials.tpaccept</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" id="permission" data-type="text" data-pk="6" data-url="test.php" data-title="Enter permission">itemcase.buy</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use the below selector to iterate over hyper links and call X-editable function individually.

```
$.each($('#parent div.col-md-4>a'), function(item){
   item.editable();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, they made me realize that i can just change id to class and select '.permission' instead of '#permission'.